# detecting in form1 that form2 is closed

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to detect that form2 is closed in form1.  I have this so far

```
    private void AddStageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
        if (form2.IsDisposed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("it was closed!");
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks again!

Comment: If you use ShowDialog, the rest of the code won't execute until that form is closed, so no conditional is needed at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve by creating a "modal" new form and again checking if its disposed or not in the same method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adhere to the `FormClosed` event of form2.

Wherever you create it do:

```
form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form2_FormClosed);
```

Then create the method:

```
void form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```

You'll also want to use `.Show()` instead of `.ShowDialog()` if you want to be able to use either form, otherwise `form1` will be unavailable until `form2` is closed (which I am assuming is not the behavior you are looking for).

Answer (score 2):

In this particular situation

```
private void AddStageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show("it was closed!");
}
```

will work fine.  If you want to be able to do action within form1 while form2 is open you need to use Show instead of ShowDialog.  Then you can create a handler for form closed within form1.

```
form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form2_FormClosed);
```